# How to upload and sync PAF scripts to ALM

Tags: ipaf, paceautomationframework

What are the steps to **Sync/Upload** PAF Scripts to execute test cases in ALM from IDE?

Answer (score 0):

PAF Scripts can be uploaded to ALM from IDE.

1. To Upload the scripts, click on the dropdown next to the Run button
   on the IDE and select “Run Configurations…”
2. On the “Run Configurations” window, select “ALM Sync” → Select tab
   “Arguments” → Enter the flow id and flow xml path in following
   format. createTestCase flow_id flow_xml_path
3. Click on “Run” button and the Test Script should be uploaded to ALM.